# How to convert a string to a number in the where statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert a string to a number. I have values stored like $4,215.35 so I want to convert that to a number so I can check if the value is greater than 50 or not.

If the value is greater than 50 then I want to update a field called `first_sale_on` with a time stamp.

Here is what I have done

```
UPDATE 
    account AS m
    INNER JOIN ps_weekly_activations AS t ON t.mid = m.mid
SET 
    m.first_sale_on = CAST(CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(t.Date_First_PL_Sale, '%c/%e/%Y'), ' 00:00:00') AS datetime)
WHERE 
    t.Date_First_PL_Sale IS NOT NULL
    AND CONVERT(REPLACE(REPLACE(Private_Label_Net_Sales, '$',''), ',', ''), DECIMAL(18,2) ) >= 50;
```

I get the following error:

> "Error code 1366: Incorrect decimal value '' at row -1..

The error means that I am trying to do operation on a string in the where statement. but I am not sure why the conversion is failing here. If the convert works then the query should execute with no problems.

Comment: Instead of using `convert` in your `where` clause, try using `cast`... does the error still pops out?

Comment: I did that did not work either

Comment: On the off chance that you have control of this database, perhaps you should store your dollar values as floats or decimals in the first place, rather than as strings.

Comment: @dg99 The problem here is that table is populated using an excel file. So the giving values are string and not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and the solution. The problem is that there was a bad data in that table that was throwing the query off.

To solve it I have added a check print i do the arithmetic. the check will check if the value is a number or not

This my new query (I hope my answer helps someone else)

```
UPDATE 
    account AS m
    INNER JOIN ps_weekly_activations AS t ON t.mid = m.mid
SET 
    m.first_sale_on = CAST(CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(t.Date_First_PL_Sale, '%c/%e/%Y'), ' 00:00:00') AS datetime)
WHERE 
    t.Date_First_PL_Sale IS NOT NULL

AND CONCAT('', REPLACE(REPLACE(Private_Label_Net_Sales, '$',''), ',', '') *1 ) = REPLACE(REPLACE(Private_Label_Net_Sales, '$',''), ',', '') 

    AND CONVERT(REPLACE(REPLACE(Private_Label_Net_Sales, '$',''), ',', ''), DECIMAL(18,2) ) >= 50;
```